# Why I have the error : Entered captcha is wrong, try again

Tags: php, configuration, phpmyadmin, captcha, hcaptcha

I installed hCaptcha in phpMyAdmin using the following settings:

```
$cfg['CaptchaMethod'] = 'checkbox';
$cfg['CaptchaApi'] = 'https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js';
$cfg['CaptchaCsp'] = 'https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com';
$cfg['CaptchaRequestParam'] = 'h-captcha';
$cfg['CaptchaResponseParam'] = 'h-captcha-response';
$cfg['CaptchaSiteVerifyURL'] = 'https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify';
// This is the secret key from hCaptcha dashboard
$cfg['CaptchaLoginPrivateKey'] = 'my_secret_key';
// This is the site key from hCaptcha dashboard
$cfg['CaptchaLoginPublicKey'] = 'my_site_key';
```

[hCaptcha Checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFyZ1.png)
[hCaptcha Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCWFg.png)

However, when I try to connect with the hCaptcha, I get the error : `Entered captcha is wrong, try again!` However, I fill it in correctly. When there is no captcha I can connect to my server.

I tried to desativate https, change site key...